# Lookahead/lookbehind issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have the string: " to " and would like to split it by white space but white space must not be inside <>. So the output I'm looking for are 3 strings:

```
<a b>
to
<c>
```

I know I should use lookbehind and lookahead to check whether white space is inside <> but somehow I don't know how to construct such a regular expression.

```
Regex.Matches("<a b> to <c>", @"(?<!<.*?)\s+(?!.*?>)") // Doesn't match space only before and after to
```

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern might work for your needs:

```
(<.+?>)|((?<=>).+?(?=<))
```

Basically we match `<text>` or (see the `|`) text that occurs between two end brackets

Comment: Thank you, it works! Would you know how to write a regex to match the spaces? ("Inverted" match.) I'm just curious so I'd learn lookahead/behind REs better

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean? What output do you want to get from this match?

Comment: If I used Regex.Matches, I'd get 2 items. First one is space at value[5], second one is space at value[8]. Value = "<a b> to <c>". I.e. "<a b>THIStoTHIS<c>". Thank you!

Comment: One option would be this `(?<=>) | (?=<)` pattern, though it relies on your input following this specific format

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `Regex.Split` approach with a regex that matches one or more whitespace chars when not preceded with `<` (and any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`) and not followed with `>` (preceded with 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`):

```
var results = Regex.Split(s.Trim(), @"(?<!<[^<>]*)\s+(?![^<>]*>)");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F!%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*%3E%29&i=%3Ca%20b%3E%20to%20%3Cc%3E)

**Details**

- `(?<!<[^<>]*)` - a [*negative lookbehind*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-negative-lookbehind-assertions) that fails the match if, immediately to the *left* of the current location, there is a `<` followed with 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?![^<>]*>)` - a [*negative lookahead*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-negative-lookahead-assertions) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`.

[image]